# A jilt whose ear was never whispered close (From "On Fame" by John Keats)

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

I've met an ambiguous line in Keat's "[On Fame](http://www.bartleby.com/126/57.html)":

> FAME, like a wayward girl, will still be coy
>         To those who woo her with too slavish knees,
>       But makes surrender to some thoughtless boy,
>         And dotes the more upon a heart at ease;
>       She is a Gipsey,—will not speak to those
>         Who have not learnt to be content without her;
>       A Jilt, **whose ear was never whisper’d close,**
>         Who thinks they scandal her who talk about her;

What could this mean, "her ear was never whispered close"? Nobody has ever shared their secrets with her? But how could that emphasize or confirm her position as a jilt? I could imagine a jilt whose ear has been *whispered close* in that sense and still that would not prevent her from being a jilt.

The line seems so out of touch with the rest of the poem that I feel there must be something I've failed to notice.

Comment: "Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), principally because the only person who can comment on what they meant is the author. It seems to *me* that Keats is saying Fame has never let anyone get close enough to whisper sweet nothings to her.

Comment: Oh, sweet nothings! Great, seems to be so indeed. I associated whispering with gossip and otherlooked that sense. Thank you, Andrew! I know I'm guilty of transgressing into the criticism realm, but I find that some lines are so obvious to native speakers but pass over my head.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I agree with your intepretation of the line, but not with the principle that authors alone can say what their works mean. See [Plato *Apology* 22a-c](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0170%3Atext%3DApol.%3Apage%3D22), where Socrates notes that the poets who actually wrote the poems are often quite the *least* adept at explicating them.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I was only explaining the off-topic reasoning. Perhaps I should have said *is likely to be the author,* as you have proved that it's not universally so. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall point of these quatrains and indeed the whole sonnet is that Fame bestows her favors on those who do not seek or care much for fame. A very similar kind of thing is said or rather sung about Love, *l’Amour,* by the title character in Bizet’s opera *Carmen* in her “Habanera”; and the same principle underlies the title of Joseph Heller’s comic novel *Catch-22,* where those who seek to be excused from flying more bombing missions are deemed *ipso facto* sane and so are not excused, and those who do not seek to be excused are insane and qualify to be excused (but are not because they do not ask—if they asked, they would be denied).

Fame is a jilt in that (in accordance with this overall point) she disappoints those who woo her. Whispering close [in] her ear is a type of such wooing, but she so shuns those inclined to woo her that they never get close enough.

Comment: Excellently played, sir!  I was very puzzled over the whole poem.  Although I once wrote a poem (of three or four lines), poetry is definitely not my strong suit!